# How to set a variable layout in Jade?

Tags: layout, express, pug

I want to set a customisable layout path in Jade.

I get the path from my app and put it in Express in `res.locals._layout` like it (app.js is under `/lib`):

> app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
>
> app.set('view engine', 'jade');
>
> res.locals._layout = layout_path;

Then I try to pass it to `extends` in my view like it:

> extends _layout

I also tested `extends #{_layout}`, with also bad results...

Here is the error I get for the last one:

> ENOENT, no such file or directory '/root_path/views/#{_layout}.jade'

The [doc](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) is not verbose on such a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is supported by jade. The `extends` is resolved when the template is compiled, before any res.locals state can be applied. But there are some workarounds mentioned in this thread.

https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/520

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround only allows to toggle between two predefined layouts, so I think I will use a 2-step rendering as described [here](http://blog.techniv.fr/2013/express-js-3-et-les-layout-ejs/) (FR - I have not found english equivalent)